# JQuery Mobile Page Scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a script that I need to run when a particular page loads. But it needs to run AFTER JQM has done its thing and enhanced the page.

I put the script tag inside the div for the page and that works fine.

But if I bind to pageshow, then my script gets run for EVERY page that ever gets shown afterward too, which is not what I want.

Where is the right place to put my script so it gets run once per load of this page, after the JQM initialization has completed?

Comment: Note that `pageshow` is deprecated and will be removed on 1.5, instead use `pagecontainershow`. However, new events can't be bound to specific pages, they fire on each and every page. Give that page and ID and on that event get active page's ID. Compare results and run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of jQuery Mobile *page events* are deprecated and replaced with `pageContainer` events. Those new events can't be attached directly to pages, they are omitted on `$.mobile.pageContainer`.

The equivalent to `pageshow` is `pagecontainershow`, use that event to retrieve active page's ID. Compare retrieved ID with your *special* page's ID and run code accordingly.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
  var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage")[0].id;
  if(activePage == "pageX") {
    /* code */
  }
});
```

Comment: Won't my handler get attached multiple times for reloads of the page?

Comment: @jeff it will. If you're adding listeners, You need to `.off()` and then `.on()` to eliminate multiple code execution.